# Pasar data de una tabla a otra con un tipo de datos diferente en el destino

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Buenas tardes a todos.

Estoy tratando de pasar los registro de una `tablaA` hacia `tablaB`.
La `tablaA` tiene todas sus columnas en formato varchar ya que su origen son archivos csv

1- Como puedo pasar datos de una tabla a otra sin perder información?

2- Error al realizar en insert linea 2

- Tablas

```sql
CREATE TABLE TablaA
(
    id_compania VARCHAR(200),
    compania VARCHAR(200),
    id_venta VARCHAR(200),
    fecha_venta VARCHAR(200),
    precio VARCHAR(200),
)


CREATE TABLE TablaB
(
    id bigint identity(1,1),
    id_compania INTEGER,
    compania VARCHAR(100),
    id_venta bigint,
    fecha_venta datetime,
    precio Numeric(10,2)
)
```

- Insert

```sql
INSERT INTO tablaB (id_compania,compania,id_venta,fecha_venta,precio)
SELECT id_compania,compania,id_venta,fecha_venta,precio (select convert(datetime, fecha_digitacion_orden), select(convert(numeric,precio)))
FROM tablaA
```

Comment: Que el origen sea de un csv, no significa que estés obligado a guardar todo en formato texto. Otro problema que no aclaras, es que dices que la tabla a es la que tiene todos los campos varchar pero en tu código es la tabla b quien tiene todo varchar. Otro tema a tener en cuenta es que si tu id (tabla a) es alfa numérico (A125C - por ejemplo) no podrás guardarlo en la tabla b ya que es de tipo entero. De todas formas, si quieres pasar todo de una tabla a otra deberás castear los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar errores, puedes usar `TRY_CONVERT()` al momento de insertar. También es bueno validar que no se envíen nulos que representen valores incorrectos.

```
INSERT INTO TablaB(
        id_compania,
        compania,
        id_venta,
        fecha_venta,
        precio
)
SELECT  TRY_CONVERT( int, id_compania),
        LEFT( compania, 100),
        TRY_CONVERT( bigint, id_venta),
        TRY_CONVERT( datetime, fecha_venta),
        TRY_CONVERT( Numeric(10,2), precio) 
FROM tablaA
WHERE TRY_CONVERT( int, id_compania)      IS NOT NULL
  AND LEN( compania)                      <= 100
  AND TRY_CONVERT( bigint, id_venta)      IS NOT NULL
  AND TRY_CONVERT( datetime, fecha_venta) IS NOT NULL
  AND TRY_CONVERT( Numeric(10,2), precio) IS NOT NULL;
```

También puedes ver las filas que generan errores cambiando un poco la consulta.

```
SELECT  id_compania,
        compania,
        id_venta,
        fecha_venta,
        precio
FROM tablaA
WHERE TRY_CONVERT( int, id_compania)      IS NULL
   OR LEN( compania)                      > 100
   OR TRY_CONVERT( bigint, id_venta)      IS NULL
   OR TRY_CONVERT( datetime, fecha_venta) IS NULL
   OR TRY_CONVERT( Numeric(10,2), precio) IS NULL;
```